# jquery define tabs with content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like to use JQuery for creating tabs.  My issue is all jquery tab definitions follow this design.

```
<div>  
<h4>Heading</h4>  
  <div>  
    <ul>  
     <li><a>Tab 1</a></li>  
     <li><a>Tab 2</a></li>  
     <li><a>Tab 3</a></li>  
    </ul>  
     <div>Content for Tab 1</div>  
     <div>Content for Tab 2</div>  
     <div>Content for Tab 3</div>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

However, I need a design like this:

```
<div>  
  <h4>Heading</h4>  
  <div>  

    <div><a>Tab 1</a></div>
    <div>Content for Tab 1</div>  

    <div><a>Tab 2</a></div>  
    <div>Content for Tab 2</div>  

    <div><a>Tab 3</a></div>  
    <div>Content for Tab 3</div>  

  </div>  
</div>
```

Is the above design possible?

Also, I need the tabs to be recognised by css class and not ids (since I create tabs dynamically through code).  Is this possible too?

**Update:** Thanks for all the great minds who helped me, I'm able to establish what I wanted.  I have used the inputs from the below posts and improved them for placing multiple tabs in a page.

**Find the demo here:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/sunalive/VHPwP/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/q7Lqq/

**HTML CODE:**

```
    <div class="contents-wrapper">  
          <h4>Heading</h4>  
          <div class="tabs-container">  

              <div class="tabs"><a>Tab 1</a></div>
              <div class="contents" style="display:block">Content for Tab 1</div>  

              <div class="tabs"><a>Tab 2</a></div>  
              <div class="contents">Content for Tab 2</div>  

              <div class="tabs"><a>Tab 3</a></div>  
              <div class="contents">Content for Tab 3</div>  

          </div>  
    </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
    $('.tabs').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.contents').hide();
        $(this).next().show();
    });
```

**CSS**

```
    .contents-wrapper{
        width: 222px;
        font-family: tahoma;
    }

    h4 {
       height: 40px;
       line-height: 40px;
       background: #666;
       color: #fff;
       font-size: 26px;
       padding: 0 15px;
    }

   .tabs-container { position: relative; }

   .tabs {
       float:left;
       background: #ccc;
       height: 30px;
       line-height: 30px;
       padding: 0 16px;
       border-right:1px solid #666;
       border-bottom:1px solid #666;
       cursor: pointer;
    }

    .tabs:hover { background: #f4f4f4; }

    .contents {
       position: absolute;
       margin-top: 31px;
       padding: 15px;
       border: 1px solid #ccc;
       width: 190px;
       font-size: 12px;
       font-weight:bold;
       display: none;
     }
```

Hope it will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is working right away.  It is also working for nested tabs.  However, the nested content div overflows the parent content div (because of the positon: absolute property).  Tried changing it, but changing distorts the tab placement.  I would like the parent div adjusting itself to the total height according to content.  Can you please help me with this too?

Comment: Ravi, I am not good in Programming (Logic), Kindly see this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/Gfxvk/ if you are good in programming so you can achieve this in your own way. In this demo I want to select every 4rth tab and on behalf of that i want to add 31px from top for contents div. That's all

Comment: Thanks Ahsan.  I figured a way out of it.

Comment: Updated my question with a link to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

add some classes :-)

```
<div>  
  <h4>Heading</h4>  
  <div class="parent">  

    <div class="link"><a>Tab 1</a></div>
    <div class="content">Content for Tab 1</div>  

    <div class="link"><a>Tab 2</a></div>  
    <div class="content">Content for Tab 2</div>  

    <div class="link"><a>Tab 3</a></div>  
    <div class="content">Content for Tab 3</div>  

  </div>  
</div>  



$('.link').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.content').hide();
    $(this).next().show();
});

or

$('.link').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.content').hide().end().next().show();
});
```

Comment: This seems to be the one I need.  I'll try this today.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below are links for creating tabs dynamically:

http://blog.favrik.com/2009/08/11/dynamically-adding-jquery-tabs-round2/

http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2010/01/26/dynamic-tabs-jquery.aspx